# How to restrict a user to only see their own profile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a view (`resources/view/front/auth/profile.blade.php`) and my route in file *web.php* is:

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}','UserController@edit')
    ->name('profile')
    ->middleware('profilecheck');
```

My problem is that when a user logs in and gets redirected to their own profile page (`http://exmaple.com/profile/2`), he/she can change the URL to `http://exmaple.com/profile/3` and see other users' profile.

I want to use a middleware to check authenticated users id with URL parameter `{user}`. The `$user->id` will passed to the `{user}`, but I have no idea how.

Middleware `UserProfile.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\User;
use Closure;

class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // $request->user()->id
        // Auth::user()->id

        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

Comment: fi it's logged, just use a "/profile" as url, and in the controller use `return view(...)->with('user', auth()->user())`, or define some policies https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization

Comment: remove the option to pass the id in the url and just access the user through Auth::user() using the auth facade in the controller to return the current user

Comment: @Berto99 , thank you , i just did what you said, and it worked .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can protect the route simply by removing the user id from the URL, but getting it through the authentication session instead.

So, your route signature should goes from:

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'UserController@edit')->name('profile');
```

To this:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'UserController@edit')->name('profile');
```

So, in your controller, instead of getting the user id from the request:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
     $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
     // ...
}
```

You could get the logged-in `User` through the `Auth` facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function edit(Request $request)
{
     $user = Auth::user();
     // ...
}
```

or just the `auth()` helper:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
     $user = auth()->user();
     // ...
}
```

This way, you are masking the URL to avoid a malicious user of doing things that he/she shouldn't.

Comment: This is one way to do it but then you miss out on things like Route Model Binding. Using the auth middleware and Polcies is likely to be better in the long run

Comment: @Spholt Why would you miss Model Binding? If you need to bind something else just defined it in your route and receive it in the function. I'm not saying that this should be done in every single request, just in this particular case of blocking a user to modify his profile. This approach is also valid to edit user related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

Your route

```
Route::get('/profile', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@profile',
    'middleware' => 'profilecheck'
]);
```

Your middleware

```
class CheckUserMiddleware
{    
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {

    if(!auth()->user()) {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Controller 
 public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2) {
            return view('author.setting.settings');
        } else {
            Toastr::info('you are not authorized to access', 'Info');
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }

// Route 
Route::group(['as'=>'user.','prefix'=>'user','namespace'=>'Author','middleware'=>['auth','user']], function (){

    Route::get('/setting','SettingsController@index')->name('settings.settings');

});
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59906733/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).